# How do we show if $|A|\le|B|$ then $|B|\not\lt|A|$ using Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, cardinals, alternative-proof

The books states I have to make use of the Cantor-Berstein Theorem which states if $|A|\le|B|$ and $|B|\le|A|$ then $|A|=|B|$.

Attempt: Suppose $|A|\le|B|$, then $|A|\lt |B|$ or $|A|=|B|$. If this is true, then $|A| \not\lt|B|$ and $A\neq B$ is false. Hence $(|A|<|B|\lor A=B) \lor (|A|\not\lt|B|\land A\neq B)$ is true. Hence $(|A|<|B|\lor |A|\not\lt|B|\lor|A|\neq|B|)\land(|A|<|B|\lor|A|=|B|\lor|A|\neq|B|)$. Hence $(|A|\neq |B|)\land(|A|<|B|)$. Hence $|A|<|B|$. Hence $\neg(|B|<|A|)$. Hence $|B|\not\lt|A|$.

However, I did not use Cantor-Bernstein Theorem? Is my proof correct? What should I have done instead?

Comment: Presumably the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).  Your argument seems to presume that the infinite cardinals  have a total linear order (which seems to require the axiom of choice)  while the theorem is independent of the axiom of choice

Comment: What is your definition of $|A|\lt|B|$? For me $|A|\lt|B|$ means "$|A|\le|B|$ and $|B|\not\le|A|$" in which case "if $|A|\le|B|$ then $|B|\not\lt|A|$" is a tautology, and doesn't need the Cantor–Bernstein theorem or anything else.

Comment: @Henry: the OP's name for this theorem is sometimes used (as it says in the Wikipedia page you give a link to). I don't know what you mean by "can be ordered" in this context: the S-B theorem certainly doesn't imply that any two sets are comparable.

Comment: But where do you get "suppose $|A|\le|B|$, then $|A|\lt|B|$ or $|A|=|B|$? (You wrote $A=B$ but you must have meant $|A|=|B|$.) I believe **that** requires the Cantor–Bernstein theorem, doesn't it?

Comment: @bof According to the textbook $|A|<|B|$ means $|A|\le|B|$ and $A\neq B$.

Comment: @Arbuja: Did you mean to write $|A|\le|B|$ and $|A|\ne|B|$ in that last comment?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I assumed $(A\neq B) \land (|A|\lt|B|)$ is a tautology to $|A|\lt|B|$. Am I correct?

Comment: @Henry: No, the Cantor–Bernstein theorem. If you want to name it after people who actually contributed to it, the Borel–Dedekind–Cantor–Bernstein, arguably also König.

Comment: @Arbuja: I can’t make any sense of that, I’m afraid.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You can give an alternative proof using Cantor Bernstein Theorem.

Comment: @Arbuja: You still haven't answered my question. If your textbook says that $|A|<|B|$ means that $|A|\le|B|$ and $A\ne B$, your textbook is wrong. It has to be $|A|\ne|B|$, not $A\ne B$.

Comment: You assume that both $|A| < |B|$ and $|B| < |A|$ are impossible.  Why?  Why can't those both be true?

Comment: $(|A|<|B|\lor A=B) \land (|A|\not\lt|B|\land A\neq B)$ cannot be true: it is equivalent to a statement of the form $\phi \land \lnot\phi$. You went wrong in your attempt to translate the ambiguous statement "$|A| \not\lt|B|$ and $A\neq B$ is false" into formal logic. (And as pointed out in other comments you should be saying $|A| = |B|$ rather than $A = B$.)

Comment: Don't write $A = B$ (or $A \ne B$) when you mean $|A| = |B|$ for example $|\mathbb N| = |\mathbb Z|$ and $|\mathbb N| \not < |\mathbb Z|$ but $\mathbb N\ne \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Henry. Engelking, in General Topology, calls it Cantor-Bernstein.... Simmons, in Introduction To Topology And Higher Analysis, calls it Schroeder-Bernstein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|B|<|A|$, then $|B|\le|A|$ and $|B|\neq|A|$ (according to textbook).

Assume $|A|\le|B|$, then by Cantor Bernstein Theorem if $|B|\le |A|$ and $|A|\le|B|$ then $|B|=|A|$; however, $|B|\neq|A|$. This is a contradition. Hence $|A|\not\le|B|$. Hence if $|B|\lt|A|$ then $|A|\not\le|B|$. Therefore by contraposition, if $|A|\le|B|$ then $|B|\not\lt|A|$.

Answer (score 4):

If $|B|<|A|$, then there is an injection from $B$ to $A$. You’re assuming that $|A|\le|B|$, so there is also an injection from $A$ to $B$. The Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem then says that $|A|=|B|$, contradicting the assumption that $|B|<|A|$. Thus, $|B|\not<|A|$. That’s all there is to it.

Comment: Sorry I unaccepted your answer. I created a [new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4119706/125918) and which is clearer to a beginner like me. What do you think?

Comment: @Arbuja: From my point of view it’s essentially the same answer expressed slightly less clearly, but sometimes clarity is a matter of taste. It’s correct, and I’ll upvote it as soon as I post this comment.

Answer (score 1):

fleablood’s comment hits the nail on the head: you can’t just jump from $|A| < |B|$ to $\neg (|B| < |A|)$ because this assumes Cantor-Bernstein.  There is no inherent contradiction between $|A| < |B|$ and $|B| < |A|$ that follows trivially from their definitions; the OP is subtly assuming there is a contradiction because the notation is suggestive (this makes it a good notation, but proof by notation alone is not a proof).

If you expand out the definitions, it just means that

1. there is an injection from $A$ to $B$,
2. there is an injection from $B$ to $A$,
3. there is no bijection between $A$ and $B$.

Cantor-Bernstein is precisely equivalent to saying that these three conditions cannot simultaneously occur.  Without it, it’s entirely plausible that $|A| < |B|$ and $|B| < |A|$ at the same time.

Comment: @ErikWong What do you think of my [new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4119706/125918)

Comment: @Arbuja It looks right to me, but I don’t see much difference between your answer and Brian’s answer.  I guess your answer is a little more explicit about the contradiction, and that’s helpful.  I thought it was important to address what was wrong with your original approach so as not to accept his (correct) answer blindly.